# Why wouldn't you want to use the `--save` option for npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I read about using the `--save` option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install) and and it says that it will add the installed package to your `package.json` file. But why isn't this automatic? Wouldn't you always want this?

My understanding is that the `node_modules` is the directory that actually holds the code of your package and `package.json` is the reference/list of all the packages you have installed so that when you push it up to a repo, you only push the latter up and not the former, to save space.

Then when other people clone or fork off your repo, they will have the `package.json` to reference and install all the necessary packages to work off of your project.

Thus, wouldn't you always want your packages to be in the `package.json` in order for everyone to get what is needed?

Comment: Maybe you're experimenting with a new module and don't know if you're going to keep it yet.

Comment: @webbm so at that point you can just easily uninstall it right?

Comment: Tough to say why npm decided to do this, but the popular alternative [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)'s add command does save dependencies by default.

Comment: @stackjlei Yep, that'd be a simple example. Not sure about the actual decision that went into the design of the process of course.

Comment: Calls for speculation, but I will point out that you sometimes want to save to dev dependencies rather than dependencies and also you don't want to save for a global install.  I realize there are ways around both, just making the observation

Comment: @Paul you can't run `save` for a global install right? what would be the point? it's just on your machine anyway at that point? Or is there still a package.json file somewhere on your machine?

Comment: That's my point, if Mom were to autosave without the --save flag, it makes their logic more complicated to account for --save-dev and -g options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the --save option for npm install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Comment: [`npm install` now saves to package.json by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html). You need to use to --no-save flag if you don't want it getting added to your project's package.json

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With package managers like **Bower** or **npm**, I think `--save` is not automatic for the following reasons:

1. Not all dependencies are production dependencies (see `--save-dev`).
2. Sometimes you need to test a package without altering your `package.json`.
3. You may prefer to install locally some packages that your colleagues installed globally on their computer.

Packages installed without `--save` are not considered as dependencies and are kept separate. You can detect them easily as **extraneous packages** with `npm ls` and remove them instantly with `npm prune`.

Now if you think extraneous packages are a bad thing, you can of course use `--save` everytime you install a new package. For practical reasons, be aware that you can use the `-S` shortcut instead of `--save`. Moreover, if you often forget to use the option, you could define an alias in your shell.

Finally, if you use **Yarn**, notice that the `yarn add` command will add each package as a dependency. No `--save` flag anymore.

Comment: if I install a package without a --save option the first time to test it out and end up liking it and want to keep it in my package.json, do I have to enter its name manually or can I just re-run the npm i with the --save option?

Comment: You could modify your `package.json` by hand (not recommended) or re-run `npm i <pkg> -S`.

Comment: [`npm install` now saves to package.json by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html). You need to use to --no-save flag if you don't want it getting added to your project's package.json

Answer (score 3):

To quote one of the npm maintainers:

> In the last couple years, quite a bit has changed here, which renders parts of this issue moot:
>   [...]
>   It’s [...] easy enough to run `npm config set save true` as an end users.
>   That said, there are still a number of rough spots when making `--save` the default:
>
> - While the cognitive load of having to remember `--save` or `--save-dev` at install time is an irritating niggle, it does force you to choose at install time whether a package is a `dependency` or `devDependency`.
> - Moving packages between sections in `package.json` is still a little more difficult than it should be, which makes cleaning up after things when you forget to specify that somethi[ng] is a devDependency.
>     [...]
>     I don’t think it’s in the best interests, as a result, to opt everyone into saving everything by default.

(from https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5108)

Comment: [`npm install` now saves to package.json by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html). You need to use to --no-save flag if you don't want it getting added to your project's package.json