# unable to install npm packages in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, installation

i am beginner for Node.js , i try to install some packages like express.js, underscore.js using Node.js by NPM but every time im trying to install using following command:

`npm install express`,

```
npm install underscore
```

Its showing error.
please Refer following image,.
please help me to fix this.
how to install packages in npm by node.js

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: command line shows wrong command `npm view express`

Comment: Did you check your network settings as recommended by the error message?

Comment: Network setting??

Comment: can you ping the registry server? ```ping registry.npmjs.org```

Comment: Its showing following
C:\Workings\NodeJs_Projects\Training>ping registry.npmjs.org

Pinging a.sni.fastly.net [151.101.112.162] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 53.89.198.3: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 53.89.198.3: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 53.89.198.3: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 53.89.198.3: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 151.101.112.162:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

Comment: Hmm, I see a lot of "Destination host unreachable." Are you using a proxy or a firewall that might be blocking access?

Comment: Try ```npm config ls -l```  and let me know what the line says for proxy

Comment: its showing some long details.,

Comment: You should see a line that says ```proxy = <value>```  What is the value?

Comment: it showing "proxy = null"

Comment: now what can i do for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

You type `npm view` insted of `npm install`. Also you can add --save option

`npm install underscore --save`

[What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score -1):

as some other say, u looks having problem with network.. i've never try "npm view express" but in my case it give a list of all the repository and file .. are u sure u have installed node?

node -v

if u have something like 
v6.9.4 (this is my current version.. yours can be more recent)

try to create "package.json" using:
npm init -y

and then:
npm i --save express

Comment: Yes i installed in my machine