# had issue with installing firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, npm

I was trying to install firebase for my react native project with

```
npm install --save firebase
```

but I got errors. What worked for me was

```
npm install firebase --save
```

for whatever reason. why? what's the difference ?!

Comment: What errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you go and read the [documentation of these flags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), you find that they also put --save/--save-dev after the package names. e.g.:

```
npm install sax
npm install githubname/reponame
npm install @myorg/privatepackage
npm install node-tap --save-dev
npm install dtrace-provider --save-optional
npm install readable-stream --save-exact
npm install ansi-regex --save-bundle
```

Another example would be this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35849725/4831083) to the question that asks what the `--save` flag is used for. The answer also uses `--save` after the package names are listed.

All I know is that that's just how npm works. Every single example of installation I've seen has that same method of installation: `npm install <package-name> <flag>`. The exception being the `--global` flag.