# Unable to use vue-airbnb-style-datepicker with Nuxt

Tags: plugins, webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm all new with Nuxt so this might be stupid question.

I have a Nuxt project where I want to use this plugin
[vue-airbnb-style-datepicker](https://mikaeledebro.gitbooks.io/vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/)

I fallowed the installation and installed this to my project:

```
npm install vue-airbnb-style-datepicker --save

npm install date-fns
```

then in the plugins folder I made a file called **vue-airbnb-datepicker.js** and added this code inside

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import AirbnbStyleDatepicker from 'vue-airbnb-style-datepicker'
import 'vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/dist/styles.css'

const datepickerOptions = {}

Vue.use(AirbnbStyleDatepicker, datepickerOptions)
```

then in the **nuxt.config.js** I added my plugin

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-airbnb-datepicker.js'],
```

After all this when i run my app i got

**ReferenceError Element is not defined**

I can post the full error message but I do not think that is relevant.

Comment: maybe it's about this plugin `date-fns` ?

Comment: @sovalina It says in the installation "NB: This plugin is dependant on VueJS 2.x and date-fns (for date manipulation). Make sure you have these dependencies installed."

Comment: Why did you run `npm install date-fns` and not `npm install date-fns --save`?

Comment: @Schwesi there should not be any difference from using --save. If you are confused about it, try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to disable it for server side e.g.

```
{ src: '~/plugins/vue-airbnb-datepicker.js', ssr: false }
```

Comment: where am I adding this configuration please? package.json?

Comment: ah, like so: https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/issues/704#issuecomment-483975422-permalink

Answer (score 0):

On a hunch:

The folder names in the `node_modules/date-fns` are like `addWeeks` and in `/node_modules/vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/dist/vue-airbnb-style-datepicker.es.js`, they are imported as e.g import `addWeeks` from `date-fns/add_weeks`;

Changing imports might actually help.

Comment: Please follow these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) when answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)