# how we can install fontawesome by npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

When I try to install I get error like this:

```
$ npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\package.json'


npm WARN Desktop No description
npm WARN Desktop No repository field.
npm WARN Desktop No README data
npm WARN Desktop No license field.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving the 'npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<username>/package.json'' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895493/solving-the-npm-warn-saveerror-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-users)

Comment: 1) you not initiated a js project using node modules, or you are in the wrong directory trying to install a package. the issue is not fontawesome

Answer (score 1):

This kind of messages you get when you try to `npm install` in a directory that hasn't been initialized as an npm package. Have you done

```
npm init
```

in the folder, at any moment in the past? If not, do that.

(BTW it looks like you're trying to use your Windows desktop directly as the work folder. Decidedly do not. Create a folder for your project somewhere else).

Answer (score -1):

Fontawesome has paid plans. Maybe someone uploaded paid data and then deleted it. Try simply npm i font-awesome instead

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
  npm i font-awesome
```

This should work