# npm error when installing Electron-Js from npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, electron, linux-mint

Tried to install the Electron-JS to my Linux Mint 20.1. I built Node Js from source (v.14.5), and installed Chromium from apt, both successfully. When trying to install Electron from npm, I got the following errors/warnings(?):

```
Downloading electron-v11.3.0-linux-x64.zip: [========] 100% ETA: 0.0 seconds 

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/maranga/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/maranga/package.json'
```

[image: npm WARN]

1. What do they mean?
2. Will they stop me from using electron?
3. Should I just build electron from source/binaries to prevent further issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to starting by :

```
npm init / yarn init
```

in your directory project if you want to develop a project.

And after this command you will have a package.json and package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

So no sooner did I post this question did I find a [question for a similar installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50895493/13807486) with a few answers.

The rationale is that you need a `package.json` file wherever you're installing a project, so run `npm init` first in your desired directory before installing. Also you can just install globally as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50895493/13807486)

EDIT: [Here is a 101 on npm and installs.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54447694/13807486)