# Module not found: Can't resolve '../axios' in 'F:\React\react-complete-guide\src\Component'

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm getting this compilation error in my `React` project where I try to send a `GET` request:

```
./src/Component/Form.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../axios' in 'F:\React\react-complete-guide\src\Component'
```

**CODE:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import axios from '../axios';

class Form extends React.Component{

state={UserName:""};

onChangeHandle=(event)=>{
    this.setState({UserName:event.target.value});

}

handleSubmit= (event) =>{

event.preventDefault();
console.log('form submit');

axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.UserName}')
   .then(
       resp=>{
       console.log(resp);
    })

};


render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" 
                placeholder="Github UserName"
                value={this.state.UserName}
                onChange={this.onChangeHandle}   />
            <br/>
            <button type="submit"> Add card </button>
        </form>    
    )}
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: It seems axios is not imported/installed properly. Is this axios, npm package or some file in your project? How are you importing it? Please share the code of `src/Component/Form.js` to see how you have imported it.

Comment: I have  added the code.

Comment: It seems that axios node module is imported incorrectly. Instead of `import axios from '../axios';` it should be like `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: I have also tried the above solution ....but not work

Comment: I have read this issue on github but there is no perfect anser or solution for this

Comment: Can you add the github issue link here? I installed the axios package (`npm install axios --save`) and was able to successfully import the package by `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: if everything is correct, just restart your app

Answer (score 44):

**Try:**

**1.** Installing **axios** module with **npm**: `npm install axios --save`

**2.** Replacing your import code: `import axios from '../axios';`
with the: `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: npm install axios --save,saved me,thanks for the answer,can you explain whats mean by --save flag?

Comment: You're welcome :) `--save` basically tells **npm** to add the package to the dependencies list.

Comment: `--save` is not needed for npm 5.0.0 and above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install

Answer (score 7):

The code

```
import axios from '../axios';
```

Is for importing a file, and the **'../** ' is the path to the upper folder. Hence **"../axios"** means it's looking for a file **"axios.js"** in the outer folder of the current file.

An axios file is created to create an instance of axios to have some default parameters set as baseURL, intercepters etc.

Here, you have to import the module axios,given that you already have installed axios with,

```
npm install axios --save
```

You can import it as,

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Replace your import axios line with the above line

Answer (score 3):

In your second line, please look at the error

```
import axios from '../axios';
```

that should be

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I hadn't installed the axios module in my project folder. Make sure you are in the project directory when installing the axios module using:`npm install axios --save`

After installation simply run it using

import axios from 'axios';

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine for me.

- Installing axios module with npm: npm install axios --save

Answer (score 1):

I once had that error but I fixed it with `npm install axios --save`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the axios package is missng and needs to be installed.
Run below command in your project root directory, to install it.

`npm install axios --save`

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

just open project directory
after npm start, you might be seeing error like this:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdWgB.png)

after that, just type:
npm i axios

in cmd opened in project directory and hit enter.
after this the axios will be installed in project.
as:
[view of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg3h3.png)
After this, if you re start by npm start, you may get message that port 3000 is already in use, so use other port, type Y, hit enter, and you should be fine to go.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody uses `yarn`, do

`yarn add anxios`

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios'", make sure to install the axios package by opening your terminal in your project's root directory and running the command:

```
npm install axios --save
```

or

```
yarn add axios
```

then restart your development server.