# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles' (when deploying to heroku)

Tags: reactjs, heroku

i have a react application and trying to deploy it to Heroku and when runnung `git push heroku master`

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles'

I searched for similar issues and installed the latest versions of npm, node and metarial-ui 
also i tried `npm install @material-ui/core` ..didn't work.

here is the full error-log file

> -----> Build succeeded!
>   =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git
>   =====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
>          Writing `static.json` to support create-react-app
>          Enabling runtime environment variables
>   amusement-parks-europe@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_a49639db14111a3c4e29b2f3e9e25c49
>   react-scripts build
>   Creating an optimized production build...
>   Failed to compile.
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/styles' in '/tmp/build_a49639db14111a3c4e29b2f3e9e25c49/src'
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! amusement-parks-europe@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the amusement-parks-europe@0.1.0 build script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-08T20_29_28_807Z-debug.log
>    !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
>    !     Push failed

and the project can be found on github 
[react app using google Api](https://github.com/MaherAbedah/Top_10_amusement_parks)

thanks for any help, I tried many ideas and came to no solution .

Comment: First thing I noticed is there is no `@material-ui` mentioned in your dependencies (package.json). Try `npm install @material-ui --save`

Comment: I did it and now it's in the package.json, but nothing changed

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the problem was solved according to the answer from @samokasha , 
the solution was using 
`npm install @material-ui/core --save`

I used the same command before but I missed the `--save`

thanks for the help.

Comment: As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Comment: just run `npm install @material-ui/core@next`

Comment: It worked for me but Whats the difference between the above and `code npm i --save @material-ui/core`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MUI 5
You need to change this

```
v5
import { withStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';


V4
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your package.json file doesn't include material-ui. Try 'npm i -s @material-ui/core'

Comment: Check your package.json file. There you have material-ui installed. You need to install the @material-ui package with the following commands: "npm install @material-ui/core --save". Don't forget the "@"

Answer (score 1):

for me was >> ‍`npm i @material-ui/core --force`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Check your react version and run:

```
npm install @material-ui/core --save
```

or run:

```
npm install @material-ui/core@next
```

Answer (score 0):

Below command solves my error:

```
npm i @material-ui/core --force
```