# React Native : error undefined Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-vector-icons

I have installed react native using ::

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

Everything works fine, untill I install and NPM package. 
I created three pages without installing new package. When I installed Vector icons for react native using ::

```
npm i react-native-vector-icons
```

I get  alots of warning when Command is done ::

npm WARN react-native-safe-area-view@0.11.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-navigation-stack@0.6.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-tab-view@0.0.77 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN react-native-drawer-layout@1.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

But package seems to be installed ::

- react-native-vector-icons@6.1.0
  added 47 packages from 29 contributors, removed 329 packages, updated 658 packages and audited 21565 packages in 83.604s
  found 0 vulnerabilities

**After that When I run :: expo start**
I Get following error ::

```
[16:19:03] Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
[16:19:03] Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
```

Now as per error i ran npm install and then expo start.

everything seems to be fine, project starts running on expo emulator.
**BUT** when I edit anything and save it produces another error ::

```
Error
16:25
undefined
Error
16:25
Building JavaScript bundle: error
Info
16:25
Building JavaScript bundle: 99%
```

and emulator turns red with unclear error as in screenshot attached:
Is there any mistake I made that produced that error. 
Please let me know the fix so that I can install npm packages run with react native. 
Help appriciated

[image]

Comment: It happens after installing any NPM package

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions may work.

I.Try to restart the node server which is hosting the app, right now.

II. Delete `node_modules` then `npm install`.

III. Reset the cache `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

IV. Remove `react-native-vector-icons` from package.json and try with `npm install react-native-vector-icons --save`

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Sateesh. I have tried deleting and running command again. reset cache as well. I will try the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution add --save to your command :

> npm install --save react-native-vector-icons

why you need --save :

[What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)