# Does publishing to NPM add dependencies?

Tags: npm, package.json

The package [react-canvas-draw](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw) has the following in its [package.json](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/blob/develop/package.json) on GitHub:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "catenary-curve": "^1.0.1",
    "lazy-brush": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "all-contributors-cli": "^5.4.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "nwb": "0.21.x",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1"
  },
```

However, when I [view the package on NPM](https://registry.npmjs.com/react-canvas-draw), I see:

```
            "dependencies": {
                "catenary-curve": "^1.0.1",
                "codecov": "^3.5.0",   // <-- note
                "coveralls": "^3.0.4", // <-- note
                "lazy-brush": "^1.0.1",
                "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
                "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.0"
            },
            "peerDependencies": {
                "react": "16.x"
            },
            "devDependencies": {
                "all-contributors-cli": "^5.4.1",
                "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
                "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
                "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
                "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
                "eslint": "^4.1.1",
                "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
                "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.34.1",
                "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.6.0",
                "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
                "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
                "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
                "nwb": "^0.21.5",
                "react": "^16.2.0",
                "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
                "style-loader": "^0.19.1"
            },
```

I noted above the two additional packages that I see: codecov and coveralls.  They're also displayed in the [user-friendly site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas-draw?activeTab=dependencies).

#### Why are these in the NPM package entry, but not in the GitHub source?

---

My only thought: the words [`codecov`](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/search?q=codecov&type=Code) and [`coveralls`](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/search?q=coveralls&unscoped_q=coveralls&type=Code) only really exist in the [.travis.yml](https://github.com/embiem/react-canvas-draw/blob/94531e5896ba4bee688f84f6ad4d203d76057f01/.travis.yml#L6) file:

```
before_install:
- npm install codecov coveralls
- npm install nwb
```

...So, `npm publish` is detecting the `npm install` commands and adding dependencies to `package.json`?  I can't find anything to support this, but I don't have any better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your assumption, executing `npm install` as of [NPM v5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/2344348) will add them to the `package.json` as dependencies. The subsequent `npm publish` that travis runs is then including this "updated" dependency list in the package.

---

It's interesting that they're shipping with those packages, as they're primarily "dev dependencies" so don't need to be included in the distributed bundle. You may want to open an issue or pull request that either declares these as dev dependencies in the `package.json` or includes a `--save-dev` in the `.travis.yml`.

(Though the latter would not be that great either as it would "add" those as dev deps of the published module that are not reflected on the github source).