# In Node-RED, how do you reference a javascript libary after using npm to install

Tags: javascript, npm, node-red

**NodeRED**

I am looking to use the **xterm.js** library from https://xtermjs.org/, which I installed with the command `npm install xterm`.

I would like to use the template node to run the following code but I do not know how to import the xterm.js library.

[image]

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="what-path-do-i-use/xterm/css/xterm.css" />
<script src="what-path-do-i-use/xterm/lib/xterm.js"></script>

<div id="terminal"></div>

<script>
var term = new Terminal();
term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
term.write('Hello from \x1B[1;3;31mxterm.js\x1B[0m $ ')
</script>
```

I used docker-compose to launch the project:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  node-red:
    image: nodered/node-red:latest
    user: root
    environment:
      - TZ=America/New_York
    ports:
      - "1880:1880"
    networks:
      - node-red-net
    volumes:
      - .node-red-data:/data

networks:
  node-red-net:
```

**Not looking to CDN**

A CDN link like below is a temp solution, but there should be a way to reference npm modules libraries.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/3.14.5/xterm.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/3.14.5/xterm.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `npm install` only installs things, which is not what you want. You want the fact that it should be installed to be _saved_ so that from now on it'll _always_ get installed. Use `npm install ... --save` (or `npm i -s ...` if you like to shortened commands)

Comment: Thanks, I am new to npm and I ran with --save option as you specified. I do have the xterm model in the node_modules folder, but I am not sure where to go from there. I found this [Import Libary Discussion](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/import-a-library-by-global-method-vs-script-src-method/14823/10), but I am not sure how to include the js or css libary.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans *As of npm 5.0.0, installed modules are added as a dependency by default, so the --save option is no longer needed*, check [What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/1889685).

Comment: ... sure but I assume you visited the link you put in your post? https://xtermjs.org/ clearly shows which path you should use pretty much immediately, in the "Getting Started" section. Does following that example not work?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the complication here is they want to use this in the context of Node-RED - so it isn't quite as straightforward

Comment: Correct, this is specific to Node-RED and files are not found on page load.

Answer (score 2):

Node-RED won't just serve up files from npm installed modules. You will have to do one of the following:

1. Enable the `httpStatic` path in your `settings.js` file (path to this is listed in the early log output) and place the `xterm.js` file in  that path. It can then be accessed with something like http:localhost:1880/xterm.js
2. Use a http-in/http-out pair of nodes with a file node between them to server the file up on a path of your choice. The file node will need to be set with the full path to the `xterm.js` file.

You haven't said which directory you were in when you ran the `npm install` so I can't suggest where the file will have ended up.

Comment: I used docker-compose and set the volume to mount the `.node-red-data` folder to the `/data`.  So /data/lib and data/node_modules.