# Installing lodash.filter

Tags: node.js, lodash, npm-install

What is the difference between `npm install` and `npm install --save`?

I try to install `lodash.filter` using `npm install --save lodash.filter`. I thought it install the packet + describes it in package.json.
But the system says, she do not understand, what `lodash.filter` is.

Should I install `lodash.filter` again using `npm install lodash.filter`? Or what should I do? Uninstalling `lodash.filter` and trying to install it again?

Comment: `npm install` and `npm install --save` are same. You should add some detail here. What does npm say? `npm i lodash.filter` would be enough to install `lodash.filter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

To check installed modules use `npm ls` to show all your modules and `npm ls lodash.filter` to see, if it is installed. I think the system showed the mistake, because imported `lodash.filter` wasn't used in program (I followed the other steps in the tutorial and it rendered well).