# Installation of expressJS using npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm, terminal, npm-install

What's the difference between these  What does *--save* do in the command

*$ npm install express --save*

*$ npm install express*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [installing](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install) a module using `npm` the `--save` option saves the module name and version to the `package.json` file. It is the default and the module will be saved event without the parameter. Having the modules listed in the `package.json` file allows you to install all the needed modules for a project using `npm install`

It should be mentioned that this saves a runtime dependency. If there is a module which is only used during development (e.g. `nodemon`) you install it using `--save-dev` so it is saved as a development dependency. Check the link above for all the `npm` options

Answer (score 2):

The save flag adds `express` to your `package.json` file. This file is used to store information about your project, such as its dependencies.

By doing `npm install express --save`, your project officially records that you have express installed and that your project needs it to run. Now lets say you sent your friend your source code, they can just run `npm install` and it will check `package.json`, recognize you installed express as a dependency, and it'll install it for them.

[What is the --save option for npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install)