# Uncaught Error: This is a placeholder package

Tags: vue.js, signalr

I cannot install the microsoft/signalr package inside my Vue.js project.

Import

```
import signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
```

Install Command:

```
npm install @microsoft/signalr
```

During runtime I get:

```
Uncaught Error: This is a placeholder package!
```

Comment: Are there any other packages you're referencing? Seems unlikely that it's related to the SignalR package.

Answer (score 0):

USE =>

```
npm install @microsoft/signalr --save
```

Comment: Unless the OP is using a very old version of NPM, [the `--save` option is no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/4468423).