# React server won't start after installing styled-components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components

**Disclaimer**: this is my first question on Stack Overflow, so apologies if it's not formatted correctly. Please let me know how I can improve it or if more details are needed.

I tried to install styled-components for my React app with the following command `npm install --save styled-components`.

Before I did this, my server started up just fine with **npm start**.

After install, React tries to start up the development server but it stops and returns the following errors:

```
cacheEntry.sizeOnlySource = new SizeOnlySource(size);

TypeError: SizeOnlySource is not a constructor

at updateFileWithReplacementSource (project-directory/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:756:37)
    at updateWithReplacementSource (project-directory/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:738:8)
    at processMissingFile (project-directory/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:801:8)
    at project-directory/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:843:10
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (project-directory/node_modules/memfs/lib/volume.js:698:17)
```

Initially, I tried uninstalling the styled-components package. Same errors. Then, I tried updating webpack with **npm update webpack**.

I googled the errors but they were all for problems that seemed unrelated or that are now fixed.

[Support Webpack 4.29.0 breaking change](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin/issues/74)

[output.futureEmitAssets option breaks compatibility with source map upload plugins](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8883)

[library target umd - Uncaught TypeError: x is not a constructor](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8480)

I did come across [a post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578796/what-is-the-save-option-for-npm-install) explaining that `--save` is no longer necessary as of npm version 5.0.0. Perhaps it's the source of the error?

Note that I installed the styled-components package on a separate branch of my project, but the server still won't start when I switch to the main branch and I'm getting the same errors.

Honestly, I have no idea what's going wrong or how to fix it. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: before the `Starting development server...` line I get after running **npm start**, there's some kind of message about webpack being deprecated. I hadn't noticed that before, but it flashes by too quickly for me to read it and I can't scroll up to see the message. I created a new React project from scratch to see if the server would start. It does, but I'm still getting the aforementioned messages.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @MansiRaja nope, no progress as of yet, sorry :(