# Where does "npm install -g <package>" install the package?

Tags: macos, npm, npm-install

I have installed some packages using `npm install -g` and was wondering were they were actually installed?

If I use `npm install` they are installed in the current directory under `node_modules` it appears.

I understand how to use the -g flag from [(when to use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909986/when-should-i-use-npm-with-g-flag-and-why)  and [(how to use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm).

Comment: Do you want to know the folder where global dependencies are installed?

Answer (score 9):

When you do `npm install -g <package>”` then it means you want to install that particular npm module system wide (globally). And when you do without the g option, then module would be installed locally inside the current directory called node_modules.

The -g(global) directive tells `npm` to install the package in the global shared node_modules folder and usually you get that where `nodejs` resides(*Path: C:\Program Files\nodejs*).This will also allow you to access the module from the command-line at global level.

You can also ***check where global packages/libraries are installed:***

Run below command

```
npm list -g  or  npm root -g
```

**In windows:**

```
C:\Users\admin>npm list -g
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

### **In mac: you find node_modules here**

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Whenever you put -g then it installed that file globally and that can accessed in any folder you wants then you don't need to install again again same package.

For more [details](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).

You can also ***check where local packages/libraries are installed:***

run `npm list`  or  `npm root`

And, when you simply install then that particular package restricted to that folder.
So, whenever you package dependencies at global level then you need to put -g while installing folder.So,

- If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program,
  using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of
  your project.
- If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on
  the command line or something, install it globally, so that its
  binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.
  [check this](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-packages-local-global/).

Hope it helps.Thanks