# Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, module, require, npm

I am learning nodejs at the moment on Windows. Several modules are installed globally with npm.cmd, and nodejs failed to find the installed modules. Take jade for example,

```
npm install jade -g
```

Jade is installed in directory `"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules"`, but the following code will fail with a `"Cannot find module 'jade'"` error,

```
var jade = require('jade');
```

However, the code will run successfully when jade is locally installed (without -g option in npm). I don't want to use locally-installed modules, it's a waste of disk space for me. How can I make the globally-installed modules work on Windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471965/what-will-be-the-difference-in-requiremypackage-js-and-requiremypackage/15471995#15471995

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni: not sure how that's relevant here. Adding '.js' to the require doesn't solve the problem on Windows.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: I think you misunderstood the answer. The code given in that answer is a code of Node.js, which shows how it looks for the package you require. So if you understand where and how it looks for files, you can then solve your issue more easily.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/how-do-i-install-a-module-globally-using-npm/5830153#5830153 npm install forever -g

Comment: fix path and try with another command line like powerShell

Answer (score 376, accepted):

Add an environment variable called `NODE_PATH` and set it to `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules` (Windows XP), `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` (Windows 7/8/10), or wherever npm ends up installing the modules on your Windows flavor. To be done with it once and for all, add this as a System variable in the Advanced tab of the System Properties dialog (run `control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3`).

Quick solution in Windows 7+ is to just run:

```
rem for future
setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
rem for current session
set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

It's worth to mention that `NODE_PATH` is only used when importing modules in Node apps. When you want to use globally installed modules' binaries in your CLI you need to add it also to your `PATH`, but without `node_modules` part (for example `%AppData%\npm` in Windows 7/8/10).

---

*Old story*

I'm pretty much new to node.js myself so I can be not entirely right but from my experience it's works this way:

1. **-g** is not a way to install global libraries, it's only a way to place them on system path so you can call them from command line without writing the full path to them. It is useful, for example, then node app is converting local files, like **less** — if you install it globally you can use it in any directory.
2. node.js itself didn't look at the npm global dir, it is using another algorithm to find required files: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules (basically its scanning every folder in the path, starting from the current for **node_modules** folder and checks it).

See similar question for more details: [How do I install a module globally using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817874/node-js-npm-is-not-installing-module-in-the-default-path)

Comment: Thanks very much, the links you provided are very helpful, I am much clearer now, although the module-searching algorithm looks a bit complicated. Finally I use the environment variable NODE_PATH to reference the global module path, `set NODE_PATH=C:\Documents and Settings\DevUser\Application Data\npm\node_modules`, and it works as expected. It's strange that globally installed modules are positioned in '%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules' on Windows, meanwhile, there cannot be quotation marks in NODE_PATH.

Comment: Glad to help. Didn't changing NODE_PATH broke path to standard node.js modules, like FS?

Comment: @beyonddoor Anything regarding Ivanov's question?

Comment: Even I was wondering why my `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules` do not have the module which I just installed using `npm install -g express` and It was available in `C:\Documents and Settings\swapnil\Application Data\npm\node_modules`

Comment: Thanks @beyonddoor for pointing out that you cannot have quotation marks in NODE_PATH.

Comment: in Windows 8 the path is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: If you want to find out where your global node_modules directory is, run the command `npm list -g`.  The first line of output will be the parent of the global node_modules directory-- in other words, the global node_modules directory is `{output}\node_modules`.  It also prints out the install directory when you run `npm install --global {xyz}`

Comment: Dear Google, please show this answer when any lost soul searches for: 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: @cowlinator Thank you for `npm list -g`--I've been searching all over for ways to figure out if npm had indeed installed gulp, even read an article titled "An Absolute Beginner's Guide to Using npm" and found nothing. It's the small things that elude beginners.

Answer (score 42):

I know i can awake a zombie but i think this is still a problem, if you need global access to node modules on Windows 7  you need to add this to your global variable path:

```
C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Important: only this without the `node_modules` part, took me half hour to see this.

Comment: Alternatively, for Windows 8 users
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Thanks for the advice on removing the `node_modules` part, was struggling with this too!

Answer (score 34):

if you are in the windows7 platform maybe you should change the NODE_PATH like this:
`%AppData%\npm\node_modules`

Comment: it's in **appdata\roaming** on windows 8 aswell

Comment: I'm on windows 8.1 with npm 2.5.1, and I've got my NODE_PATH set as documented, but it still can't find my installed packages. Thoughts?

Comment: In windows 10 it should just be %AppData%\npm

Comment: In my case (W10) it was %AppData%\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 28):

For making it work on windows 10 I solved it by adding the folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to my PATH. Having `\node_modules` appended like this: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` did not work for me.

Comment: Or, more simply, `%AppData%\npm\`

Comment: Man it's weird that worked!  I've been hunting this issue for two days, literally.  This is the most obscure solution I've tried and the first one that worked.  Thank you so much.

Comment: yes just add to the `path` environment variabele, then we can run it directly in windows 10

Comment: It would showing how to actually perform this with an example, instead of saying things such as "just add to..."

Answer (score 14):

I'll just quote from this node's [blog post](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)...

> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> - If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of
>     your project.
> - If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its
>     binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.
>
> ...
>
> Of course, there are some cases where you want to do both.
>   Coffee-script and Express both are good examples of apps that have a
>   command line interface, as well as a library. In those cases, you can
>   do one of the following:
>
> 1. Install it in both places. Seriously, are you that short on disk space? It’s fine, really. They’re tiny JavaScript programs.
> 2. Install it globally, and then npm link coffee-script or npm link express (if you’re on a platform that supports symbolic links.) Then
>      you only need to update the global copy to update all the symlinks as
>      well.

Comment: `They’re tiny JavaScript programs.` Some of these libraries are certainly not tiny!

Comment: @UpTheCreek I'm confident that he was referring to size in the scope of disk space. They are text files. They are objectively small.

Answer (score 12):

To make it short, use `npm link jade` in your app directory.

Comment: It seems `npm link jade` can't work on Windows, npm returns an error message as follows:`npm ERR! Error: npm link not supported on windows`

Comment: It does now, as for version v0.8.9

Comment: @beyonddoor: You need to run `npm link` from a Administrator command window.

Answer (score 12):

Tried to add/edit environment variables and come to conclude that:

1. Edit/add `User variables` (of the upper box) instead of `System variables` (of the lower part); otherwise you have to "run as administrator" to get it work.
2. Append `;%AppData%\npm` to `Path` in order to use it as a command line tool (if supported, like `jshint` and `grunt-cli`).
3. Create `NODE_PATH` and set it `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` in order to `require('<pkg_name>')` in scripts without install it in the project directory. (But [`npm link` is suggested](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) for this requirement if you're working on OS with `mklink` such as Vista and newer.)

Test environment:

- Win 7 (Ent., 64-bit, SP1), Node.js 4.2.4, npm 2.14.12
- Win 8.1 (Ent., 64-bit), Node.js 0.10.30, npm 1.4.21

Answer (score 12):

I had a terrible time getting global modules to work. Eventually, I explicitly added `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the PATH variable under System Variables. I also needed to have this variable come before the nodejs path variable in the list.

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. running on windows 8

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me also, thank you!

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me but I had to use forward slashes in the path.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue on Windows 7, running

```
npm install -g gulp
```

as administrator while being logged on as a normal user.

**Solution:** When executing the same installation as normal user (not "run as admin" for cmd) all was fine. I guess it is related to the default install and search path.

Comment: To clarify this point a bit more...
When Node is installed as an administrator it updates the system path to include a reference to the administrators global node module folder. When a new user install something globally it installs to a different node module folder. Each user other than the user that installed Node will need to update their path to include their global node module folder.

If you install and use node on the same account this will not be necessary.

Comment: Windows 8.1 pro with nodejs v6.9.4, to set the path run: C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat

Answer (score 4):

From my expierience with win8.1 npm installs modules on 
`C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` 
  but dumply searches them on
`C:\Users\[UserName]\node_modules`.

One simple solution reference module in application by full path:

```
var jsonminify = require("C:/Users/Saulius/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/jsonminify");
```

Comment: This approach only works for me if I use forward slashes instead.

Comment: This is a hack at best.

Comment: whoa no need to take it personally. Im just saying if you work on this code with other people it's not gonna work

Comment: @Ringo apparently. And there are many ways to solve that. But if you just pilloting smth like I was it can at least point you to the right direction. From my expierence you start with unperfect code and then improving it.

Comment: @saulius I can get on board with that! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For windows, everybody said you should set environment variables for nodejs and npm modules, but do you know why?
For some modules, they have command line tool, after installed the module, there'are **[module].cmd** file in **C:\Program Files\nodejs**, and it's used for launch in window command. So if you don't add the path containing the cmd file to environment variables **%PATH%** , you won't launch them successfully through command window.

Answer (score 4):

For me worked on Windows 10 `npm config set prefix %AppData%\npm\node_modules`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, trying to install bower with `npm install -g bower`

I think this was because **node was installed by another user**, not me.

I uninstalled node, and then I reinstalled it. During installation, I saw this text for the option *Add to PATH > npm modules*:

Message in node installation

[image]

After node installation, I executed `npm install -g bower` again. And now bower works.

Sure is not necessary reinstall node with own user, like me. Solution must be via *NODE_PATH* or *PATH* variables, as other users have explained.

This is only to remark that this problem occurs only if node has been installed by another user (or if during installation the option *Add to PATH > npm modules* has not been marked).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could add to `~/.npmrc` right [prefix](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npmrc.html). I've got `C:\Program Files\nodejs` for 64 Win7.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this question because I want to use node.js with visual studio 2015 on my new computer with windows 10. I used node.js on windows 7 and 8 and 8.1 Never a problem node.js finding a module. I use a legacy node.js 0.10.39 because I have to use this version  because of the serial and RFXCOM module.

The answer for windows 10 is to set the NODE_PATH in the enviroment variables with C:\Users\User\node_modules.

Comment: Er, no.  (Windows 10 here..)  I see some modules at `C:\Users\User\node_modules`  I see some modules at `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`  I see some modules at `C:\Users\User\node_modules`  Also located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`  Not sure how this happens.  Which is which, and why'd they do it that way?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add following to `Path` variable under `System variables`. Setting variable under `User variable` did not work for me. I am using windows 11.

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, I had to locally install gulp in the folder:

C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

```
npm install gulp
```

This fixed my issue of "gulp is not recognized"

Answer (score 0):

Just download and re-install the node from [this](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and this will fix all the path issues.

Don't forget to restart your command prompt or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers did not work for me. The only thing that worked eventually was to add the %AppData%\npm to the environment Path variable, **AND** to delete the two ng files in C:\Program Files\nodejs.

The ng packages were not installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules, so it was apparent that using the ng binary from the nodejs directory would not work.

I am not sure why it searched in this directory, because I already configured
- PATH environment variable
- .npmrc in the C:\Users\MyUser
- Tried to add system variables and/or NODE_PATH

Answer (score 0):

I was trying `pnpm prisma generate` and `npm prisma generate` and none of them worked. But then I tried with the npx command, like below.

```
npx prisma generate
```

And this line of code saves me, it sounds a little bit weird but it does working atleast on my project.

Answer (score -4):

if you are using windows , it takes some steps ,
1) create a file called package.json

```
 {
  "name": "hello"
, "version": "0.0.1"
, "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  }
}
```

where hello is the name of the package   and * means the latest version of your dependency

2) code to you project directory and run the following command

npm install

It installs the dependencies

Comment: This doesn't install it globally (which the question asks).  This pulls the dependency into the app

Comment: I've tried everything listed above to try and persuade my node.js installation to recognise globally installed modules, and NONE of it works. Even after uninstalling and reinstalling node (v8.11.3 LTS), every time I try to issue the require("mongodb") command in a node.js script, I get the SAME error: "Cannot find module mongodb". Yet, if I issue the command "npm ll -g mongodb", NPM tells me the module is installed.

Can someone PLEASE hand me some infirmation that WORKS with this problem?

Comment: UPDATE: Saulius above has provided a workaround that actually works, namely specifying the full path to the module in the JavaScript require statement. But if his stated observation about node.js searching in the wrong folders for installed modules is correct, can someone alert the node.js developers to this? Because the problem is STILL affecting v8.11.3 LTS.