# NPM global install "cannot find module"

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote a module which I published to npm a moment ago (https://npmjs.org/package/wisp)

So it installs fine from the command line:

`$ npm i -g wisp`

However, when I run it from the command line, I keep getting an error that optimist isn't installed:

```
$ wisp 
Error: Cannot find module 'optimist'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/wisp/wisp:12:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/wisp/wisp:96:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:68:25)
    at compileScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:135:29)
    at fs.stat.notSources.(anonymous function) (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:110:18)
```

However, I have specified in package.json as a dependancy:

```
{
  "name": "wisp",
  "author": "Brendan Scarvell <bscarvell@gmail.com>",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Global nodejs file server",
  "dependencies": {
    "optimist": "~0.3.4"
  },
  "repository": "git://github.com/tehlulz/wisp",
  "bin": {
    "wisp" : "./wisp"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what to do to get this running? I know its to do with the bin part adding the executable to bin and the node_modules in that directory being empty. No idea how to resolve this.

Comment: what happens if you install without -g option?

Comment: It installs a node_modules folder in the current directory which has wisp inside that.

Comment: I know. Do you still get error?

Comment: Yep. If I try to run wisp after doing a local npm i wisp, still returns same error

Comment: I just installed your module. It's working fine for me. Where is your wisp? In my case I ran `./node_modules/wisp/wisp` which works fine.

Comment: that works fine for me too. but I want to be in a random directory and just be able to type: `$ wisp` as a global install (similar to how Express works)

Comment: works for me if I do `export PATH=$PATH:~/node_modules/wisp`

Comment: Unfortunately, having this as an open source package for people to install, Id like to not have to edit that manually. I know with Express and Hakara I don't have to.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

For anyone else running into this, I had this problem due to my `npm` installing into a location that's not on my `NODE_PATH`.

```
[root@uberneek ~]# which npm
/opt/bin/npm
[root@uberneek ~]# which node
/opt/bin/node
[root@uberneek ~]# echo $NODE_PATH
```

My NODE_PATH was empty, and running `npm install --global --verbose promised-io` showed that it was installing into `/opt/lib/node_modules/promised-io`:

```
[root@uberneek ~]# npm install --global --verbose promised-io
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/opt/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/opt/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--global',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   'promised-io' ]
npm info using npm@1.1.45
npm info using node@v0.8.4
[cut]
npm info build /opt/lib/node_modules/promised-io
npm verb from cache /opt/lib/node_modules/promised-io/package.json
npm verb linkStuff [ true, '/opt/lib/node_modules', true, '/opt/lib/node_modules' ]
[cut]
```

My script fails on `require('promised-io/promise')`:

```
[neek@uberneek project]$ node buildscripts/stringsmerge.js 

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'promised-io/promise'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
```

I probably installed node and npm from source using `configure --prefix=/opt`.  I've no idea why this has made them incapable of finding installed modules.  The fix for now is to point NODE_PATH at the right directory:

```
export NODE_PATH=/opt/lib/node_modules
```

My `require('promised-io/promise')` now succeeds.

Comment: where to set this NODE_PATH ??

Comment: @sandy where you set the NODE_PATH environment variable depends on your operating system.  I'm using a flavour of Linux, so I used `export NODE_PATH=...` to set it in the local shell such that it is exported to commands run in that shell.  To make the change persistent or available to all shells, put it in .profile or similar.  The concept as a whole is annoyingly complex to the newbie, try reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables .  For Windows, you'll want to switch to Linux.  OK, just kidding.  Try http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm or google it.

Comment: For OSX Lion, following worked for me ...  export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules I used 'locate node_modules' to track down the right path.

Comment: NODE_PATH works for WINDOWS as well. this is rooted in node modules can be installed both locally and globally.

Comment: `find /bin /opt /usr -name node_modules 2>/dev/null`       to find module location Note: on centos 6 ended up being in /usr/lib/node_modules--setting path with export worked

Comment: mac os x `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`. YMMV.

Comment: Brew: `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules`

Comment: If you installed Node.js with Homebrew on Mac OS X: Run `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` in Terminal, then add `export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules` to the end of the file. Restart the terminal window. Now running `echo $NODE_PATH` should print out `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`.

Comment: you are super awesome :) It worked for me. Basically just point the node path to the place where all your node modules are installed.

Comment: nice! this worked perfectly!
for my setup - OSX 10.10 - i updated my ~/.bash_profile and added 
 # correct path for global node-modules
 export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/

then you can reload your profile with 'source ~/.bash_profile' and everything should work fine!

Comment: Works perfectly on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: After change the `NODE_PATH` what happens with local file? if i want to require a js file in project folder?

Comment: `TypeError: app.configure is not a function`

Comment: For OSX run `locate "lib/node_modules"` to find out where npm is installing modules. Then run  `export NODE_PATH=/[your-directory]/lib/node_modules`

Comment: `echo 'export NODE_PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/\`nvm current\`/lib/node_modules' >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Users of nvm may find this related StackOverflow question helpful (Configuring $NODE_PATH with NVM): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876557/node-js-configuring-node-path-with-nvm

Answer (score 51):

add this to beginning of prog(mac):

`module.paths.push('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');`

Comment: Any way of doing that in a non-os specific way?

Comment: @UpTheCreek this **is** a non-os specific way. It's JS code, you just need to point to a node_modules that has the moduleyou are looking for

Comment: @Adelin - It's an OS specific solution because the location of global node_modules is OS specific.  E.g. if you are developing on windows, and running linux in production, then this is not a great solution.

Comment: That's easily overcome. For example you can save the node path in an env variable, for example, and replace the hardcoded path with `os.environ.nodepath` (something along these lines).

Comment: macOS Mojave 10.14.6 requires adding
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
to ~/bash_profile which is more machine independent in that the native .js code is unaffected.

Comment: You can get your global node modules path by running `npm root -g` and then using the solution above in your JS file.

Answer (score 17):

By default node does not look inside the /usr/local/lib/node_module for loading global modules.
Refer the module loading explained in http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

So either you have to 
1)add the /usr/local/lib/node_module to NODE_PATH and export it 
or 
2)copy the installed node modules to /usr/local/lib/node .
(As explained in the link for loading module node will search in this path and will work)

Answer (score 16):

The following generic fix would for any module. For example with `request-promise`.
Replace

```
npm install request-promise --global
```

With

```
npm install request-promise --cli
```

worked ([source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10422#issuecomment-323562182)) and also for `globals` and `inherits`

Also, try setting the environment variable

```
NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

Comment: There is no `--cli` argument on `npm install`.

Answer (score 11):

For some (like me) that nothing else worked, try this:

```
brew cleanup
brew link node
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 8):

I got the "optimist" module error and I just did "npm install" to resolve it. went past that error.

https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/issues/12

Answer (score 3):

On windows if you just did a clean install and you get this you need blow away your npm cache in \AppData\Roaming

Answer (score 3):

$ vim /etc/profile.d/nodejs.sh

```sh
export NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
```

Comment: That is there by default. For users it's loaded, but while run as root it's not, therefore needs to be included in root user's path.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, from [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows) what worked for me is running npm link as in

```
npm link wisp
```

Comment: A word of caution though - I did this but could not then use my zipped code with AWS lambda. I had to have the node_module created locally as in `npm install wisp --save` (without the -g option)

Answer (score 2):

I did this in simple way...

1. Un-Install node from control panel [Windows 7]
2. Install node again
3. Install protractor
   `npm install --global --verbose protractor`
   Update web driver manager.

works fine for me.

Hope this helps you....

Answer (score 2):

I got this error `Error: Cannot find module 'number-is-nan'` whereas the module actually exists. It was due to a bad/incomplete Node.js installation.

For Windows , as other answers suggest it, you need a clean [Node installation](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) :

- Uninstall Node.js
- Delete the two folders `npm` and `npm_cache` in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming`
- Restart Windows and install Node.js
- Run `npm init`or (`npm init --yes` for [default config](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json))
- Set the Windows environment variable for `NODE_PATH`. This path is where your packages are installed. It's probably something like`NODE_PATH = C:\Users\user\node_modules or C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`
- Start a new cmd console and `npm` should work fine

**Note :**

Try the last points before reinstalling Node.js, it could save you some time and avoid to re-install all your packages.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac User's It's Best use the manual installation:

> To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to
>   use a different directory. In this example, it will be a hidden
>   directory on your home folder.
>
> 1. Back-up your computer before you start.
> 2. Make a directory for global installations:
>
>    mkdir ~/.npm-global
> 3. Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
>    npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
> 4. Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
>
>    export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
> 5. Back on the command line, update your system variables:
>
>    source ~/.profile
> 6. Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.
>
>    npm install -g jshint
>
> Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g.
>   if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):
>
> ```
> NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
> ```

Reference : https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 2):

I have just met this problem of the `axios` module.
Then I tried this: run `rm -rf node_modules` and `yarn`.
And it works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on one of the test servers running `Ubuntu` under `root`. Then created a new user using `useradd -m myuser` and [installed everything](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) (`nvm`, `node`, packages) as `myuser`. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case both `node` and `npm` were in same path (`/usr/bin`). The `NODE_PATH` was empty, so the `npm` placed the global modules into `/usr/lib/node_modules` where `require(...)` successfully find them.
The only exception was the `npm` module, which came with the nodejs package. Since I'm using 64 bit system, it was placed into `/usr/lib64/node_modules`. This is not where require(...) searches in case of empty `NODE_PATH` and node started from `/usr/bin`. So I had two options:

- link `/usr/lib64/node_modules/npm` to `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm`
- move modules from `/usr/lib/node_modules/*` to `/usr/lib64/node_modules/` and set `NODE_PATH=/usr/lib64/node_modules`

Both worked. I'm using OpenSUSE 42.1 and the nodejs package from updates repository. Version is 4.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as the OP, but digging through the logs I could see `sh: node: command not found`.

It turns out that the /usr/bin/node program (symlink) is no longer installed with `apt install nodejs`.   Once symlinked `/usr/bin/node' to`nodejs`,`npm install -g @angular/cli` succeeded.

The proper way to install this on debian is `apt install nodejs-legacy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm to my env variables and then i could install stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and got it resolved by adding the below line in my zshrc.
Based on your shell you can try adding in your rc file, for bash and zsh - bashrc/zshrc files present in your home location.

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```

To directly add in zshrc file, run this command

```
echo 'export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

## Alpine / Containerization

As mentioned elsewhere, the solution is to bake into your image,

```
NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

I've also [opened up an issue upstream with `npm` apk so this gets set](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/13363)