# Express on NPM doesn't start application

Tags: express, npm

Installed latest NPM v0.10.28
Then I installed express by

```
npm install express -g
```

Then I installed app as folows

```
express testExpress
cd testExpress && npm install
```

Then I ran following command to start server

```
DEBUG=testExpress ./bin/www
```

But it gives error

```
'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Also tried

```
 node DEBUG=testExpress ./bin/www
```

Still gives error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\tmp\testExpress\DEBUG=testExpress'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

What mistake I am doing ? Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use Linux environment variable syntax on Windows.

You want

```
SET DEBUG=testExpress
bin\www
```