# global package installation by NPM

Tags: node.js, centos, npm, forever

I need to install some global packages by NPM on centOS 6.5

more specifically i need to install forever , which is a command line tool

> sudo npm install -g forever

but no way i am getting forever to run from comand line

> forever

i think there is some issue in the default location of my npm installations since i tried with few other packages and the same command line binary packages are not getting installed or may be getting installed in wrong location

can you please help me figure this out

Comment: `npm ls -g --depth=0` will confirm the packages are installed and the location.  start there.

Comment: Please use this link to correct your issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module?rq=1

Comment: @AvinashDubey thanks but i have seen that post before sending my question it didn't help since my packages gets installed in /usr/lib/node_modules/ which i think is correct

Comment: @MattBakaitis i can see forever is installed but still it is not getting run from shell when i try to

Comment: ...is /usr/lib/node_modules/ in your path?  I think that's where @AvinashDubey was going with the link...  If it isn't, that's likely the issue.

Comment: @MattBakaitis and AvinashDubey thank you very much with your comments i was able to solve my issue

Comment: @Ali please answer your own question since you solved the issue.