# All NPM COMMAND not working even I updated .bash_profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, npm

I used npm for several months. 
But after I install python/django and virtual environment, it's not working anymore.

The error is smething like this.

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli

module.js:341
throw err;
^Error: Cannot find module './cache/caching-client.js'
```

I used npm for several days but this happened first time. I searched to solve issue and found this link
[Installing MEAN Stack: npm -v module.js: 338 throw err; Error: Cannot find module './cache/caching-client.js'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948437/installing-mean-stack-npm-v-module-js-338-throw-err-error-cannot-find-modul).
But not working.

```
echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

And it occurs on all npm commands.

```
npm -v

npm init -y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the node.js again and it worked.:)

Answer (score 0):

f you added React Native manually to your project, make sure you have included all the relevant dependencies that you are using, like RCTText.xcodeproj, RCTImage.xcodeproj. Next, the binaries built by these dependencies have to be linked to your app binary. Use the Linked Frameworks and Binaries section in the Xcode project settings. More detailed steps are here: Linking Libraries.

If you are using CocoaPods, verify that you have added React along with the subspecs to the Podfile. For example, if you were using the ,  and fetch() APIs, you would need to add these in your Podfile:

for more see this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-winjs-cli/tutorial