# Nativescript; installing on command line npm issue

Tags: javascript, npm, command, line, nativescript

I am trying ton install Nativescript to make iOS apps using Javascript. I tried running the following command:

```
npm i -g nativescript
```

which resulted in the following error message:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './cache/caching-client.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:23:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:475:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Does anybody know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have an issue in your `npm` installation and your `NODE_PATH`.

Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14515868/1134380).