# NPM doesnt install dependencies

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

have an issue with npm.
Im trying to make project with ionic, but faced with problem with missing packages. 
Almost every command with ionic throws error.
For example:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

causes `"Error: cannot find module 'config-chain'"`. Then I install it manually and try again `'ionic platform add ios'`, I have `"Error: cannot find module 'next-blabla-module"`. And this repeats until I not install all the modules, which are **basic dependencies** of npm.
Check screenshot, please
[image: npm error messages]

Have read all the topics with similar issues and nothing works.
I tried to reinstall nodejs, reinstall npm, get @latest npm, reinstall ionic. Also tried `npm install npm-install-missing`.
But nothigs helps. Any suggestions how to fix that evil?

Node version 4.4.5
Npm version 3.9.5
Ionic version 1.7.15

Comment: I think your packages are installed in the wrong folder. Check this answer for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515868/3423342. Good luck!