# Can install but can't run npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble with my node.js/npm setup,

I freshly installed it via the website and it worked fine. 
It told me to make sure /usr/local/bin/npm has to be in my path and when I run
`echo $PATH` it is in there, so it should be fine.

I can now install packages (tested with `npm i webpack -save-dev`) the installation works as expected, without any errors.

But when i run `webpack` all It is giving back is `command not found` has anyone experienced 
something like this before?

Comment: It will be installed in your node_modules/webpack folder. You can prob run it with node_modules/.bin/webpack from your project root (btw it is --save-dev)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! it does run with node_modules/.bin/webpack (btw it is --save-dev), still wondering why just "webpack" isn't working.

Comment: Because although npm is installed globally webpack is not (you would have to install with the -g flag for that) .. you want it local though so that you can have different versions for different projects etc. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages?rq=1

Comment: but that would mean if i run 'npm i -g webpack' then 'webpack' should work, right? i just tried it, and it didn't

Comment: It should work - check that webpack is in /usr/local/bin and make sure that /usr/local/bin/ is on on your PATH ... otherwise something is broken :)

Comment: other than the nodejs installer said, there is actually nothing at /usr/local/bin/ instead the packages are at /Users/username/.node/bin i added export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/.node/bin to .bash_profile but it doesn't do the trick...

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is a global package install.
Try using

> npm i -g webpack

You can get help on install with

> npm help i

Comment: He probably doesn't want to install it globally really - he wants it locally with his project.

Comment: It is the same issue for global packages.

Comment: ok! in that case, like Sam suggested run webpack  from the bin folder... if you need to use webpack from command line then you should install globally.. or use webpack from within package.json npm scripts.. and node will detect the location for you

Comment: i just installed globally via 'npm i -g webpack' 'webpack' command is still not found, as mentioned it works when running directly from node_modules folder

Comment: Hi Jannik, try looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module?rq=1 Alternatively I also suggest to install nvm  with > brew install nvm

Answer (score 0):

Did you install `node v8/npm v5`?

In that case, it seems there's an open `big-bug` [ticket](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16837) on the npm repository.