# Error: Cannot find module '@kyleshockey/object-assign-deep'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have newly installed [accept-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/accept-language) npm module. After installation when I try to start the project I get below error

> Error: Cannot find module '@kyleshockey/object-assign-deep'

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPM global install "cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module)

Comment: @Sashi How come this is duplicate? That doesn't solve my issue at all

Comment: Sorry, I faced a similar problem before and it solved my problem. Do you have a different error message and/or have you already tried the answer suggested in the other question?

Comment: @Sashi what do you mean by different error message? What I got is there in the question

Comment: Note: it is OK to explain in your question _why_ a question is not a duplicate. However, it seems to be quite popular to merely state that a question is not a duplicate, with no explanation; you will discover that readers don't find that persuasive, and may vote to close anyway. If you want to prevent a question from closing as a dupe, give a convincing reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@kyleshockey/object-assign-deep` is neither direct nor indirect dependency of `accept-language` so it is a dependency (direct or not) of your app. And it didn't install correctly. Try to remove package-lock.json and run `npm install`, or maybe better try `yarn install`