# Cordova - Cannot find module 'npm'

Tags: cordova

When I run `cordova build ios` it comes up with:

```
Cannot find module 'npm'
```

What should I look for to fix this?

Comment: Has it ever run successfully? I'm wondering if npm is in the NODE_PATH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module

Answer (score 0):

So, you are running cordova build on Mac. 
Firstly - you must install Node.
Then check that cordova tools are installed.

Your issue 90% means, that some plugin ( firebase or similar more complex plugins ) tries to fetch node packages ( read as install the library to the native project ).

Comment: Yes I had it working previously and a Cordova build with no plugins works fine. It must be one of the plugins, but I am not sure which one. Once it’s in this state removing plugins doesn’t help and i am having to rebuild the project from scratch, multiple times to pinpoint it... not fun...

Comment: Just install node.js 