# How to convert html into react components by using CLI command html2react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

I am trying to implement automated process of converting html into react components. I am following below link to automatically convert html into react components.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react-components
but i am getting failure of command html2react. I also installed the package by using below command.
"npm i -g html-to-react-components". 
But still it is saying "'html2react' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM global install "cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I installed the package globally. As i installed globally so i have to place my html file in C:/Users/YourComputerName/AppData/Roaming/npm.
and then from CLI I have to open the above folder and directory in which my html2react package is installed.
And then from that directory I have to implement the html2react command.
For clear understanding i am also attaching snapshot as well. [CLI command description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr0XD.png)
Have a good learning.