# feathersjs issue feathers: command not found

Tags: node.js, feathersjs

I need to generate a new app using featersjs
and I am following the cli commands
npm i -g @feathersjs/cli
and it`s installed successfully at node_modules, then write feathers generate app
feathers: command not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM global install "cannot find module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594541/npm-global-install-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Which OS are you working on? Which terminal are you using? Do you have elevated privileges?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.4 and it`s downloaded successfully at node_modules globally