# "cannot find module" when installing npm modules on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-8, npm

I am new to NodeJS. I am trying to use npm on Windows 8.

I have installed using [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/), `cinst nodejs.install` (version [0.10.17](http://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.install)). I installed as administrator (and would prefer to run npm as a normal user).

Node itself seems to be working, I can use the REPL to run simple programs.

If I try to install something using npm, I get `cannot find module`:

```
> node npm install express

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Klas\Documents\My Dropbox\mina egna\tech\node\webserver\npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

I have read the answers on [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows) but unfortunately it is still unclear to me what I have to do.

I have tried setting `NODE_PATH`:

1. In trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/46194), I have tried setting it to  `C:\Users\Klas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` (but I had to create both the `npm` and the subfolder `node_modules` myself)
2. I have tried creating a folder `c:\node\node_module` (according to [this advice](http://csell.net/2011/10/20/setting-up-npm-for-node-js-on-windows/), even though the installation did not even create a `c:\node` folder) and setting it to that.
3. I have tried setting it to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules` (which did exist after installation)
4. I have also tried to create a `node_modules` folder below the current working directory. As I understand it that is where local npm will be installed?

None of these helped. So it seems to me that setting `NODE_PATH` is not the solution?

Using the `-g` flag makes no difference (I would prefer not to use it).

I get the same error both as normal user and as administrator (I would prefer to be a normal user).

I get the same error no matter where I execute the command, except when I do it in  `C:\Program Files\nodejs`, where I get

```
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
   at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using windows, but I'm pretty sure it's just `npm install express` on windows too.

Comment: Doh! If I do `npm install express` inside the REPL I get the message `npm should be run outside of the node repl, in your normal shell`, which I interpreted as `npm` being a subcommand to `node`, that is why I ran `node npm install express` in `cmd.exe`. Embarrassing newbie mistake.

Comment: Those other articles threw me for a loop, as they talked so much about `NODE_PATH`. As far as I can see, you don't have to set `NODE_PATH` at all, if you are content with local installs (which is recommended)

Comment: Well there are also npm modules that are just command line tools for daily usage (e.g. simple-HTTPServer). For those to be available via command line you need them in your NODE_PATH.