# Node.js module is not seen although it's installed globally (Windows)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using Windows.

I've installed `mongodb` module using next command:

```
npm install -g mongodb
```

`mongodb` module is listed when I type:

```
npm ls -g
```

But when I'm trying to do `require('mongodb');` Node gives me an `Error: Cannot find modue 'mongodb'`.
When I include `mongodb` with absolute path it's included fine:

```
require('C:\\Users\\Evgeniy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\mongodb');
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Solution: Linux. On a more serious note. Why would you install mongodb globally rather than having it on your project?

Comment: @majidarif I'm learning MongoDB at the moment and I thought it would be nice to have possibility to include it from anywhere. Maybe you right and I should install it locally. But any way I'm wondering why it doesn't work. I suppose I'm doing everything right.

Comment: @majidarif btw also I have coffee-script installed globally and it's either not available globally :(  Strange thing

Comment: You need to add an env_variable. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this must be caused by environment variables. You have to set `NODE_PATH` to `C:\Users\Evgeniy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following commmand from command prompt:
setx NODE_PATH %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules

This will set the environment variable permanently in your user profile's environment settings