# NPM cannot find module from same folder on Windows with TodoMVC tutorial

Tags: npm, reactjs, todomvc

```
PS C:\Users\Codey55\temp> npm run build

> todomvc-flux@0.0.3 build C:\Users\Codey55\temp
> set NODE_ENV=production browserify . | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js

PS C:\Users\Codey55\temp> npm start

> todomvc-flux@0.0.3 start C:\Users\Codey55\temp
> watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d .

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\User\Codey55\temp' from 'C:\Users\Codey55\temp'
```

I'm trying to run [this](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html) TodoMVC React tutorial on my Windows PC but i can't seem to get through the first steps of setting up the project. I've googled around and tried to add a [NODE_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows) in system variable with no results, does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` prior to `npm run build`?

Comment: @Daniel Haley, yes i did

Comment: Try changing the `.` in package.json's start script to `js/app.js` or `js\app.js` or `.\js\app.js`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by renaming my old react component files which were .jsx to standard .js. I read in another thread that I lost in the meantime that require works only with standard .js extensions.