# Error: Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber'

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I am trying to execute a small example of automated test using Webstorm, cucumber and protractor.
I have already installed cucumber using this command within the root of the project:

```
sudo npm install -g cucumber
```

I have already created the conf.js file and when running this command within the prompt:

```
> protractor conf.js
```

Finally, the output is:
*

```
[13:13:18] E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'cucumber'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.module.exports.load (/Users/alfredo.bazo/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/lib/cucumberLoader.js:19:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alfredo.bazo/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/index.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
[13:13:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

I have no idea what else I can do, any suggestions?

Comment: To add Cucumber as a development dependency, use Try `npm install --save-dev cucumber` -  see the [docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/installation/javascript/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I receive the error: cannot find module 'cucumber' when executing Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632398/i-receive-the-error-cannot-find-module-cucumber-when-executing-protractor)

Comment: Try searching for similar questions, and/or Googling for the error message

Answer (score 2):

There are two approach to resolve your problem, and recommend to use approach 1).

1) install `cucumber` as project local package, rather than global package.

`npm install -S cucumber`

2) install `cucumber` as global package, and you need to add below Environment variable to tell node.exe where to find and load global package.

```
NODE_PATH=<npm global package install folder path on your machine>
```

you can execute `npm config get prefix` which will print out the global package install folder path.

**Important**: After add environment variable, you need to try in new opened cmd/terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

how to overcome this :try to share video please regarding this query :  ...

install cucumber as global package, and you need to add below Environment variable to tell node.exe where to find and load global package.

NODE_PATH=
you can execute npm config get prefix which will print out the global package install folder path.

Important: After add environment variable, you need to try in new opened cmd/terminal window.