# i am new to nodejs and installed it. But npm start command is not success for me. It is showing the errors

Tags: reactjs

i am new to nodejs and installed it. But npm start command is not success for me. It is showing the errors

```
C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\reactjs>npm start
```

Here I am running command

```
> reactjs@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\reactjs
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
  throw err;
  ^
```

Error started here

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\reactjs\node_modules\webpack-dev-server    \bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\reactjs\node_modules    \webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules    /cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js
:60:12) {
```

this file is exist on the folder

```
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Om Namah Shiavay\\reactjs\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --ho
t`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely     additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-1
5T14_54_15_617Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Om Namah Shiavay\reactjs>npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server ^Ar
```

Comment: The error clearly says: **Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492240/error-cannot-find-module-webpack)

Comment: but webpack is installed in the folder "node_modules"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the **node_modules** and the **package-lock.json**, then reinstall the packages again (run the following on your powershell)

`rm node_modules -r -force`

`rm package-lock.json`

`npm cache verify`

`npm install`