# npm install error not installing BrowserSync package

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, command-prompt, browser-sync

Trying to install [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/#install)

I've followed the steps to install the package through the command line, installed **node.js** and then I went on to install **npm** through the command line.

Now when I try to install `browser-sync` with the following line `npm install -g browser-sync` you will see it is not recognized when I check the version and its the same when I try do anything like `start --server`?

[image]

***note*** tried installing another package as a test `jshint` successfully installs/uninstalls but displays the same message when checking its version.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like below? (http://www.browsersync.io/#install)

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

-g means global.

Comment: Updated my question more fitting with the installation steps. You will see it is still not recognized why?

Comment: Check this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

You have to edit windows PATH to make them executable from anywhere.

Comment: Good find! That worked a treat thanks for that... I just added an environment variable called `NODE_PATH` and set it to where the modules got installed.