# Error when installing node and npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install npm so I can install less. I just went to the `node.js` website and installed node. however, when i type `npm` in the command prompt i get the error:

`Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${APPDATA}
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:429:13
    etc.`

Any suggestions?

I think node installed because `node -v` yeilds `v0.12.7`

Comment: I think your path might not be set up right. Try over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8

Comment: thanks @ZacharyDow for the hints. i followed that and then used this link that i had seen before https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7468

Comment: No problem, so it's working for you with that fix?

Comment: @ZacharyDow I think so, it seems to work. when I typed `npm install -g less` some text appears. however it is not recognizing `lessc` as a command. is there a way to check?

Comment: when i just type `npm`my cmd shows `Usabe: npm <command>` so that looks good  i think

Comment: Alright, shall I answer with the info from that link?

Comment: hmm maybe i'm still not confident that the npm install is functional

Comment: Looks like you need to set up the NODE_PATH to get globally installed modules to work http://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/2283050 Remember that you can always --save-dev to have them work for projects now without configuration. I have the same thing happening to me actually, but I use it just fine with my local stuff.

Comment: mm thanks for the insight. what's --save-dev?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87313/discussion-between-zachary-dow-and-as3adtintin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your 'AppData' environment variable.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7468

> I just created a environment variable called APPDATA with the value
>   like this:
>
> variable : APPDATA
>
> value :C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm;npm

Comment: As of Nov 2016, it appears the `npmrc` file appends the npm folder. The above value caused all kinds of folder problems. Setting APPDATA to just `c:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming` worked. And APPDATA should be a User (not system) environment variable