# Ionic isn't recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I installed Ionic and cordova with `npm install -g ionic` and `npm install -g cordova` and when i try to launch a simple command such as

```
ionic start appname blank
```

I get the error : Ionic isn't recognized as an internal or external command.

I checked the version installed of both cordova and ionic with `npm info ionic version` and `npm info cordova version` and both are correctly installed

```
cordova : v 6.0.0
ionic : v 1.7.14
```

I tried to npm clean cache and reinstall both and it does not work either.

My environment path are the following:

```
User variable : PATH C:\Users\arnaud\AppData\Roaming\npm
System variable : path : C:\Program Files\nodejs\ is present
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you added your global node_modules PATH as an environment variable?

Comment: I tried but it does not work... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Comment: Thank you but your link didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check your `C:\Users\arnaud\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin` directory? Maybe ionic and cordova were located in there. If so, add above directory path to your environment variable; If not, just search `cordova` and `ionic` in file explorer. Hope this would help you, regards!