# Cannot run globally installed node modules in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, serverside-javascript

**Note:** I have tried almost all similar posts related to this issue and found nothing was helpful to me. Hence posting this.

**Issue**: I'm trying to install [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package in my Windows 7 machine using `npm install http-server -g`, Installation was fine, however when I try to execute it using `http-server` command in the command line I'm getting an error saying, `'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have also tried the same steps for `gulp` and the result was the same.

I have tried setting the Node Path as, `set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules;` but no luck.

Can someone shed some light here?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Have you installed the package using an admin console (Run as Administrator)?

Comment: It may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

Comment: @Oscar Do you mean opening the CMD with "Run as Administrator" option?

Comment: @DavidR Yes. At least in Linux, you need to make "sudo" to install globally

Comment: @Oscar I don't have admin privileges right now, will approach my IT support and will get back to you. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Oscar, Just realized that, I have the required admin access, and when I tried I had no luck as I'm having the same messages again. :(

Comment: Is there a `http-server` executable in `C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node_modules`? That's where it [should be installed](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) if you used `-g`.

Comment: No.. But I do have a `http-server.cmd` file created now after following @Oscar 's suggestion. It executes only when I navigate my command prompt to `users\dave\AppData\Roaming\npm`. I guess I need to use the `SET PATH` command now.

Comment: Yes! After setting the path it executes fine.

Comment: @Oscar Can you please post you suggestion as answer, so that I can mark it answered for you?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Can you please post you suggestion as answer, so that I can put a upvote for you?

Comment: @DavidR I don't think my comment is enough to count as an answer, but thanks a lot for the thought - I'm just glad you managed to figure it out.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Really appreciate your help!. :-)

Comment: @DavidR Done, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global packages needs to be installed using and administration console (CMD / Run as Administrator)