# How do you install angular-cli for windows 7

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular-cli for windows. I know the command is npm install -g angular-cli, however once I run this command I then try to do ng new  however I get an error saying "ng is not a recognized command" I checked the other questions on here saying that you have to add the folder to the PATH variable, however when I check in the folder I've tried to install angular-cli into I don't even see anything.

Here you can see I've installed the angular-cli using the provided command and that any use of the "ng" command registers and error:

[image: x]

And here you can see an empty folder with no angular-cli folders or anything for that matter:

[image: And here you can see an empty folder with no angular-cli folders or anything for that matter]

***PLEASE NOTE*** I am very new to cmd and angular and I really have no idea what steps to take here.

Comment: have you restarted your cmd instance?

Comment: @DanielA.White if you mean did I close cmd and try to run ng new test-app again yes I've tried that.

Comment: your global npm installation for angular-cli in your case is located at  'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli' (you can get it by running 'npm root -g' command). So, try to add its bin folder (where ng executable is located) to the PATH variable

Comment: @Andriy here is my path variable ***C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin;*** I added the bin folder and I still get ng is not recognized.

Comment: weird, try to run it with full path: C:\Users\Owner\AppData‌​\Roaming\npm\node_mo‌​dules\angular-cli\bi‌​n\ng new test-app,  and restart your cmd instance

Comment: also try to install and use git bash for windows (https://openhatch.org/missions/windows-setup/install-git-bash) instead of cmd

Comment: @Andriy the cmd does not work, still says ng is not recognizable. and if possible i prefer not to install anything new on my machine.

Comment: @Andriy is it possible to do without installing git bash? I took a look and it seems complicated, I'd like to stick with learning how to do it on the cmd, before adding another program.

Comment: @user7455422 Can you ensure that the contents of this folder (`C:\Users\Owner\AppData‌​\Roaming\npm\node_mo‌​dules`) contains a folder named `angular-cli` inside of it? This will verify that the CLI was actually installed to your machine.

Comment: @Brocco yes it does.

Comment: @user7455422 then you should be able to run this command from anywhere on your machine... `C:\Users\Owner\AppData‌​\Roaming\npm\node_mo‌​dules\angular-cli\bin\ng new project-name` and if that does not work, please refer to this answer about using global npm packages on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows/9588052#9588052

Comment: @Brocco but i can't, i get ng not recognized.

Comment: Here look at the step by step guide to install angular CLI http://www.tutorialfunda.com/angular/step-by-step-guide-to-install-angular-cli/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Installation of NodeJs, npm, TypeScript, AngularJS, @angular/cli on Windows 7 Professional SP 1 64-bit:**

Since I have found many valuable hints scattered on various posts only
after 'painful' search, here a compact compilation
(not my ideas but my experience). Hope it helps.

1. install Node.js Windows Installer 64-bit:
    https://nodejs.org/en/download/
    node-v6.11.0-x64.msi
2. If there is a (company-)proxy (installation behind firewall):
    configure npm against the company-proxy:
    open cmd window (not elevated, normally you have to be the login-user)

   npm config set proxy http://Proxy.Company.com:Port (replace Proxy.Company.com:Port with your proxy-settings)

   npm config set https-proxy http://Proxy.Company.com:Port (replace Proxy.Company.com:Port with your proxy-settings)

   Hints: Both settings are required, ask your admins for the correct
        url.
        If you need to propagate a user/password use the following syntax:

   npm config set proxy http://user:pass@Proxy.Company.com:Port
3. Set npm directory for packages
      (npm 3.10.10 comes with Node.js but we'll update it later):

   npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
4. Update npm to the latest version:

   npm install npm@latest -g

   Beware: npm update only works with the HTTPS-variant
        (registry https://registry.npmjs.org/).
        With the HTTP-setting (see below) you earn "shasum check failed".
5. Set npm directory for packages to the non-HTTPS-variant:

   npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

   Reason: the https-variant, which was necessary to update npm itself,
        does'nt work for all packages, e.g. @angular/cli@latest
        or angular-cli or typescript@latest either.
6. Install TypeScript:

   npm install -g typescript@latest
7. Possibly update Visual Studio 2015 to Update 3 (necessary)
       (everything also works fine with the Community Edition Update 3):
    Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
    Version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3
    Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
8. Ensure, that Visual Studio fetches the actually installed packages:
    Tools/Options, left-tree/Projects and Solutions/External Web Tools,
    right panel, move the $(PATH) entry to the top
    (above the $(DevEnvDir) entries). Afterwards close Visual Studio.
9. Install AngularJS:

   npm install angular (my version: 1.6.5)
10. Install Angular commandline-tool:
      npm install -g @angular/cli@latest (@angular/cli is the new name for angular-cli)
11. Check versions (in cmd window; my versions below):

    node -v       =>  v6.11.0

    npm -v        =>  5.1.0

    tsc -v        =>  2.4.1

    ng --version  =>  1.2.0 (@angular/cli)
12. Install optional package installer for Visual Studio
                         (see also section 'Links' below):
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.PackageInstaller
      (...Downloads\Package Installer v2.0.101.vsix)

**If something had gone wrong, restart with the following steps:**

- In C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming delete the directory 'npm'
- In cmd window: npm cache clean
   or possibly: npm cache clean --force
- run node-v6.11.0-x64.msi in repair-mode
- continue with Item (2.).

**Links:**

- https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/04/01/set-up-aspnet-mvc.aspx
- https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/08/angular2-using-angular2-with-typescript-for-asp-net-mvc-in-visual-studio-2015/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1164014/Kick-Start-with-AngularJS-and-Visual-Studio
- http://www.fladi.de/2014/02/06/howto-npm-hinter-einem-proxy-verwenden/

Answer (score 11):

Latest versions of Node.js and Angular CLI can be setup on Windows 7 in few simple steps:

**Step 1: Download Node.js**

Download the latest release of Node.js from: [Nodejs downloads page](https://nodejs.org/en/). I have downloaded Node.js for Windows 64-bit and the filename is: **node-v8.9.3-x64.msi**

**Step 2: Install Node.js for Windows.**

In Windows Explorer, locate the downloaded Nodejs .msi file. Double-click the .msi file. A set of screens will appear to guide you through the installation process. This will install Node.js and Node Package Manager (NPM) on your machine.

**Step 3: Verify Node.js Installation**

Type the following commands to check the versions of Node.js and NPM

```
node -v
npm -v
```

**Step 4: Install Angular CLI**

Angular Command Line Interface (CLI) is the easiest way to create new Angular projects. Execute the following NPM command to install Angular CLI:

```
npm install @angular/cli -g
```

After this installation, the CLI tool can be accessed by using ng commands.

**Step 5: Verify Angular CLI**

Type the command:

```
ng -v
```

I have also put all these steps in my blog: [Setup Node.js and Angular CLI](http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_79.html)

Comment: If you are run behind a proxy you can follow this tuto https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Comment: installation of cli giving me lots of error but finally npm install @angular/cli -g worked!..thanks

Answer (score 3):

Test It!

```
node -v
```

To see if Node is installed, type the above on your command line.

```
npm -v
```

To see if npm is installed, type the above on your command line.
Installing @angular/cli

```
npm install @angular/cli
```

To add this npm package to your local machine, type the above into your command line. You’ll notice a node_modules directory appear in your root where the package is now installed.

If you're having trouble installing packages, check out the helpful docs for installing npm packages locally

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `NG.cmd` is installed normally at:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
```

...where `Administrator` could be a user name.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Download Node.js

Download the latest release of Node.js from: Nodejs downloads page. I have downloaded Node.js for Windows 64-bit and the filename is: node-v8.9.3-x64.msi

Step 2: Install Node.js for Windows.

In Windows Explorer, locate the downloaded Nodejs .msi file. Double-click the .msi file. A set of screens will appear to guide you through the installation process. This will install Node.js and Node Package Manager (NPM) on your machine.

Step 3: Verify Node.js Installation

Type the following commands to check the versions of Node.js and NPM

node -v
npm -v

Step 4: Install Angular CLI

Angular Command Line Interface (CLI) is the easiest way to create new Angular projects. Execute the following NPM command to install Angular CLI:
Step 1: Download Node.js

Download the latest release of Node.js from: Nodejs downloads page. I have downloaded Node.js for Windows 64-bit and the filename is: node-v8.9.3-x64.msi

Step 2: Install Node.js for Windows.

In Windows Explorer, locate the downloaded Nodejs .msi file. Double-click the .msi file. A set of screens will appear to guide you through the installation process. This will install Node.js and Node Package Manager (NPM) on your machine.

Step 3: Verify Node.js Installation

Type the following commands to check the versions of Node.js and NPM

node -v
npm -v

Step 4: Install Angular CLI
This command will install latest version of angular command line.

npm i -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install latest version

```
npm i @angular/cli @latest
```