# npm install error ( npm install -g angular-cli ) in windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, command-line-interface, npm-install, failed-installation

> **node -v**
>
> v4.5.0
>
> **npm -v**
>
> 5.0.1

[image]

[image]

Has anyone faced this kind of issue while installing angular-cli in windows 10?

Comment: what is the error ??

Comment: Please click on the these cmd lines --> 
Tried--> npm install -g @angular/cli
Tried--> npm install -g angular-cli 

in the question.

Comment: i clicked :) please try the solution that i give it to u in the answer

Comment: npm install -g @angular/cli(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGJz9.png)

npm install -g angular-cli(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzPK.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following:

**step 0:** run this command

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

**step 1:** delete this folder: `C:\Users\%YOUR-USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

**step 2:** uninstall Nodejs from Windows

**step 3:** restart your PC

**step 4:** install a fresh copy of Nodejs from here: https://nodejs.org/en/

**step 5:** install the CLI globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: walaikum assalam @Hamed
Thanks

Comment: I had same problem installing gulp-cli, then I applied those steps and it's worked. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
$ npm remove -g angular-cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g angular-cli
```

Comment: Still not working i tried same as you mention
...
same error

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem recently running on a Windows box.

To solve:
using gitbash:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
```

uninstall node using the uninstall option on the Windows menu > Node
using gitbash:
    cd ~/AppData/Roaming
    rm -rf npm
    rm -rf npm-cache

**RESTART WINDOWS** : You must restart windows

reinstall node.js

```
npm i @angular/cli -g
```

That worked.

Answer (score 2):

Check the path(npm -v, node -v)ie for Setting Path variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/32159233/4720950

```
User Variable C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm 
System Variable C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Restart System & update,clean npm https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020014

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm cache clean
```

Uninstall prev angular cli and then install angular cli again

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete c:/users/{accountname}/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular
2. Delete c:/users/{accountname}/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng
3. Delete c:/users/{accountname}/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.cmd
4. Delete c:/users/{accountname}/AppData/Roaming/npm/ng.ps1
5. run this command in cmd

> npm install -g @angular/cli