# Akeneo installation / NODE_PATH=node_modules not recognized / yarn run webpack Error

Tags: hadoop-yarn, akeneo

I have already asked this question on git (https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/issues/7191) 
but unfortunately nobody has answered me yet, thought I would try SO.

I follow-up the akeneo-install-instruction (pim-community-standard-v2.0)
https://docs.akeneo.com/latest/install_pim/manual/installation_ce_archive.html#initializing-akeneo

```
yarn run webpack
```

https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.0/webpack.config.js

Gives me an error:

> $ yarn run sync && NODE_PATH=node_modules webpack --config
>   $npm_package_config_source/webpack.config.js --env=prod warning
>   package.json: No license field $ NODE_PATH=node_modules node
>   $npm_package_config_check --source=$npm_package_config_source
>   'NODE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For me too yarn is a problem. I ma using ubuntu 16.04 and nodejs 4.2.6

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're using windows you should remove this part **NODE_PATH=node_modules**. You should add this variable to your environment variables. There is already a question about it:
[Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows).

Second, if you trigger yarn, it goes to package.json and search for variable "scripts". Webpack doesn't know what is *$npm_package_config_source* and *$npm_package_config_check*. It looks like not initialized PHP variables, but I might be wrong.
There are 2 variables in the package.json :

```
"config": {
    "source": "vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev",
    "check": "vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/webpack/check-dependencies.js"
},
```

If so, you should change **scripts** variable in package.json to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "sync": "node vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/webpack/check-dependencies.js --source=vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev",
    "webpack": "yarn run sync && webpack --config vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/webpack.config.js --env=prod",
    "webpack-dev": "yarn run sync && webpack --config vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/webpack.config.js",
    "webpack-watch": "yarn run sync && webpack --progress --config vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/webpack.config.js --watch"
},
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, been looking for a solution for 2 days.