# Change windows profile nodemon nodejs not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I have used nodemon util to help my work in nodejs development. On my PC (Windows) I had to change my profile and after in the new profile I can not use nodemon anymore...
I have installed it again like these ways:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon

npm install --save-dev nodemon -g
```

I deleted it from node_modules and reinstall again but the same error:

`'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Comment: It was a good idea, I changed the path, related to the referenced article, but nothing changes... I got the same error...

Comment: It's worth to restart your console or even logout to apply changes.

Comment: @hsz It is the same error, after restarting my computer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time by time i tried to find out, whr is my problem, and I got it: 
I had bad value inthe path variable:

**Wrong**: C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

**GOOD**: C:\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i nodemon -g
```

**will install module globally so your windows could recognize the command**

Comment: Tanks your tip, but unfortanutelly not working for me...

*'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.* again..