# Unable to run lerna's command

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, lerna

I am trying to install lerna using npm , packages are successfully added but when I run any command of lerna it comes out as.

> **bash: lerna: command not found**

Node Version : v8.10.0

Npm Version  : 3.10.9.

Here's what I am trying:

```
$ npm install --global lerna
C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\lerna -> C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lerna\bin\lerna.js
C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm
`--lerna@2.11.0

VaibhavPC@Vaibhav MINGW64 ~/Projects/lerna init 
bash: lerna: command not found
```

Comment: You can check the below link , may it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Check the `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES` that is `NODE_PATH` is present or not.
If not, then have to append the path to `PATH` environment variable.

2) Re-install again

[image]

Answer (score 44):

Try running the command

```
npm install --g lerna
```

Comment: How is this getting upvotes? You just repeated what the OP has already tried.

Answer (score 21):

Try to use *npx lerna init* it helped in my case

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I just run `sudo npm install --g lerna`, and it works after bootstrap

Answer (score 8):

Three things:

1. Please check environment, if the path is correctly setup or not, for command not found error.
2. Second, you can go directly lerna folder and execute the command. If you are able to run from here that means problem is there in path ie point 1
3. The third option is re-install and install it again.

Answer (score 6):

just install the package globally

```
npm install --g lerna
yarn global add lerna
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when I installed lerna using yarn. Reinstalling using npm solved the issue.

Comment: you just reinstall the npm and then run this command npm install --global lerna

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue even with npm.

By explicitly adding

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

to the PATH variable under System Variables in Environment Variables solves the issue for me.

Answer (score -5):

Here's a [repo](https://github.com/AllenFang/lerna-tutorial-example) you can try to learn lerna in a independent environment