# Not able to install angular

Tags: angular-cli

I am not able to install angula, i tried with clear npm cache npm cache clean --force. but still not able to install. please help me 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ilw.png)

I am using node version - 8.11.3
Npm version - 6.1.0

Comment: please check screen short

Comment: Make sure c:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\npm is in your PATH, and restart your command line. Post the commands and the output as text, not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Add an environment variable called `NODE_PATH` and set it to `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules` (Windows XP), `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` (Windows 7/8/10), or wherever npm ends up installing the modules on your Windows flavor. To be done with it once and for all, add this as a System variable in the Advanced tab of the System Properties dialog (run `control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3`).

Quick solution in Windows 7+ is to just run:

```
rem for future
setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
rem for current session
set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

It's worth to mention that `NODE_PATH` is only used when importing modules in Node apps. When you want to use globally installed modules' binaries in your CLI you need to add it also to your `PATH`, but without `node_modules` part (for example `%AppData%\npm` in Windows 7/8/10).

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/1485453)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the environment variable has been configured like below,

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin;
```

Close cmd and reopen once.