# 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

After running `npm install -g expo-cli` and successfully installing the packages globally, `expo` is still not recognized as an internal or external command. Does anyone know how I might get around this issue using windows 10, or what to do in terms of something like a path variable.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: if installed using YARN add `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` to path

Answer (score 75):

Probably the only thing missing is to **add the expo executable to your path**.

For Windows 10, you can simply add the npm folder to your path environment variable.

1. Hit Windows key and search for `Environment variables`.
2. Inside the **Path** variable under `System variables`, add a new
   entry (entries are separated by semicolons) with this content *(**without /node_modules** )*:

`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

OR if you are using **yarn** `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` (as @Qwerty mentioned above)

3. Open a new command prompt and enter

`> expo`

You will see something like this:
[image]

Comment: This answer fixed my problem, but why the key "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm"  deleted after a period of from Path variables

Comment: If you already have path variable you can add the above by typing a semicolon

Comment: I had to run Powershell as administrator then "set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned"

Comment: This answer is a life saver! I have been plagued by this problem for a year now until I came across this post!

Answer (score 20):

I wondered it was working last night when I first installed and run the **"react-native"** project but the very next day it showed me the same error as yours.

Here is what I did in **windows 10 Operating System**:

**Add** the following **path** :

`environment variable >  System Variables > PATH > C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Now I ran the following commands one by one in CMD:

i) `npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save`

ii)  `npm install -g expo-cli`

Now start the Project and run `npm start` and now it works for me.

I didn't try this article one but it also shows the solution for the same problem,
[see here](https://thecoderain.blogspot.com/2019/04/windows-expo-not-recognized-internal-external-solution.html)

Answer (score 16):

I may be too late to answer this, but for people looking for the same error this is what worked for me.

1. Install `yarn` if you don't have it. I used the command `choco install yarn` (you'll have to install Chocolatey). If you have scoop installed, `scoop install yarn` also works.
2. Use `yarn` to install `expo` with `yarn global add expo-cli`.
3. `expo start` should work now. `yarn start` and `npm start` should also work.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have the same error and although this I haven't figured out how to solve it

Comment: It might be the solution. But, setting environment variable can solve the issue so there's no need to add another package. No offence but as an efficient solution, I would consider is setting *environment variable* instead of installing `yarn`

Answer (score 9):

Added These path of npm like this i have the same issue i fix it by adding the path to environment system

```
C:\Users\abobakr\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

After that close CMD and open it again it should work believe me

Answer (score 9):

go to the **environment variable**, then in the **user variable** section find `Path` and press the edit button, you will see a new window,  press new and add the following

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

[image]

then press ok. Now,

```
expo --version
```

Comment: I am not sure why your upvotes are not skyrocketing up the roof, but thanks! But may i know why does this actually works?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution I came out with.

I ran `npm list -g`

then copy the directory on the first line and paste in your system enviroment variables under the variable name 'path'

close all the terminals and run `expo` or any other command.

Answer (score 3):

If it still doesnt work or you can't access npm. Try setting the path with the Windows PowerShell:

1. Open Windows Powershell as Administrator
2. Type: `setx path "%path%;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm"`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

1. Download latest version of *nodejs* - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. After installing *nodejs* reboot your computer
3. install : `npm install --global expo-cli`
4. Generate a new project with - `npx expo-cli init projectName`
5. `cd projectName`
6. `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

Re-install node.js and
then run `npm install -g expo-cli` in command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 10 or 11, the solution to edit your Path variable works well.
Just make sure that you replace "YOUR_USERNAME" with your username on the computer:

This means that if my username is "Green", I will replace YOUR_USERNAME here:
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm

to

C:\Users\Green\AppData\Roaming\npm.

This [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-expo#:%7E:text=To%20solve%20the%20error%20%22%27expo,variable%20is%20set%20up%20correctly.) is very detailed in solving the problem in case if the above does not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. You must uninstall node js then install it again.
2. You must run npm install expo-cli.

It will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

For me, 
i uninstalled node.js,

i re-installed node.js,

i ran `npm install -g expo-cli`,

then ran expo --version (the expo command began to work).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `yarn global add expo-cli`, try `npm install -g expo-cli`.

I don't know why but when i go into `C:\Users\%{user}%\AppData\Roaming\npm` there isn't the expo package(and other packages that I thought I install globally by yarn) but there are other that I installed globally by npm.

If adding `C:\Users\%{user}%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to PATH variable doesn't work, give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last night, and I've recently started my journey in ReactNative. So, there might be better answers out there.

If you're following the ReactNative Official documentation, the first time npm start works fine, the subsequent ones throws an error saying `expo` is not recognized. I got around that by running `expo start` and not `npm start` ( which basically is the same thing but doesn't work for some reason ).

So, mine looks like a work around rather than an explanation as to why this happens or how to permanently fix it.

Comment: If expo is not recognized, how i run "expo start"???

Answer (score 0):

This is a more general problem where your global node modules are not in your system path. This question is what you are looking for: [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this in Windows 10 by setting Path C:\Users\[USERNAME] this line save my hrs

Answer (score 0):

uninstall expo using this command 
`npm -g uninstall expo-cli --save`
and reinstall expo using this command 
`npm install -g expo-cli`
then it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and it was not getting resolved by "npm install --global expo-cli".
Global CLI was having error as SS below -

- npm list -g --depth 0
  [image: Global expo-cli package issue]

Followed below steps to get it resolved

1. npm uninstall --global expo-cli
2. Deleted global package causing error C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli
3. npm install --global expo-cli

And expo cli worked.
Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution to Run Expo command without Environment Variable update then on your terminal use below command for windows system:

```
R:\> C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.cmd init {projectname}
```

Where you directly point the expo.cmd file rather than specifying in the environment variable.

And update the expo to C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.cmd in package.json to run the project.

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
    "start": "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\expo.cmd start",
    "android": "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\expo.cmd start --android",
    "ios": "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\expo.cmd start --ios",
    "web": "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\expo.cmdstart --web",
    "eject": "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\expo.cmd eject"
  },
```

Comment: Could you revise the answer more clearly using code blocks?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the environment path as said in other replies and the command is still not recognized, **try running whatever you're using to execute the command in administrator mode**.

I'm using VS Code terminal and expo was not recognized until I ran it as administartor.