# cmd.exe can't run any command except built-in commands

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, command-line-interface

**1. for example when i run "expo start" it shows the following message:**

'expo' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes

**2. My system variables are set to the following:**

- Path: C:\Windows\system32; C:\Windows ; C:\Windows\System32\Wbem ;
  C:/Users/Microk/AppData/Roaming/npm;  C:\Programmes\Nodejs;
  C:\Programmes\Git;
- pathtext:.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
- windir: C:\Windows

**3. My user variables are set to the following:**

- Path:c:\windows\system32; c:\windows ; c:\windows\system32\wbem; c:/Users/Microk/AppData/Roaming/npm;  C:\Programmes\nodejs; C:\Programmes\Git;
- pathtext:.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
- windir: C:\Windows

Comment: Does `find /?` work? If yes, it just can't find `expo` - that's very different from `any command except built-in`

Comment: You should not have the same locations set under PATH for both the User and System environments. Based upon what you've posted, and assuming you're not running an ancient OS,  I'd expect to see certainly the location of `powershell`, and not  the location for `npm` under System. I'd expect to see `C:/Users/Microk/AppData/Roaming/npm` under User instead, and none of the others shown. _I'm also assuming that the leading and/or trailing spaces are not really there too._ Also, have you seen [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52731872) and answers?

Comment: Also, are you sure that `expo` is not really `C:\Users\Microk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js`? which means you should add `C:\Users\Microk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin` to your User environment PATH variable list. _Please note, that this is a Windows Operating System, so the default path separator is a back slash, not a forward slash._

Comment: @Stephan yes it works. what should i do in this case

Comment: as Compo suggested: either add the path to `%PATH%` or (preferably) use the Full Qualified File Name ('"<Drive>:\full path to\expo.js"`)

Comment: Also, there are typically no SPACE characters before and after a directory in the PATH variable.

Comment: after following  @Compo instructions, and running "expo start" now it shows the following message: '"node"' is not reconized as internal or external command ...etc. hope u can help me. thank you all

Comment: You also need to have the location of `node.js` in your `%PATH%`, _(probably `C:\Program Files\Nodejs`)_, or use the absolute path to it! e.g. `C:\Program Files\Nodejs\node.js`.

Comment: thank u all guys. it worked after following ur instructions <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution was to set my enviroment variables to the following:**

**1. user variables:**

- path:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Programmes\Nodejs\node.js;C:\Programmes\Git;C:\Windows\System32;C:Wwindows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Users\Microk\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Microk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin;C:\Programmes\Git;C:\Program Files\nodejs
- PATHEXT: %PATHEXT%;.RB;.RBW
- node:C:\Programmes\nodejs\node.js
- NODE_PATH:C:\Users\Microk\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

**2. System variables:**

- Path:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Programmes\Nodejs\node.js;C:\Programmes\Git;