# Can't install expo-cli -g

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm new in react-native, I'm trying to set up my project after all package install when I tried to start `npm start` command then show me `'expo-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` this error.

ok, then I have followed the guide from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731872/expo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

after that I have added my `env path` in this way:

```
environment variable >  System Variables > PATH >
C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

then I have to install again:

`npm install -g expo-cli`

but it does not work for me, I don't know why.

when I try to run this command `npm install -g expo-cli` then show me an error like this:

```
PS C:\Users\alami\OneDrive\Desktop\React native\starter-react-native> npm install -g expo-cli
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli'     
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\expo-cli'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the      
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alami\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-21T00_58_34_585Z-debug.log
```

Comment: this seems to be a permission error. make sure the user running the code has adequate permission to run globally installed packages

Comment: @AbirTaher, Yes please can you tell me how can I solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

At least I just solved my problem in this way:

1. Search `cmd`
2. Then run as administrator
3. Then `npm i -g expo-cli`

I just solved my problem.