# How to run NodeJS CLI tools without having to type npx

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, npx

### **TL;DR**

I cannot execute commands such as `tsc` unless I include `npx` before it (e.g `npx tsc`). How can I fix this?

---

The title is a bad explanation of the problem I have.

Say I have installed an npm package with a CLI with it (typescript in this example). And the CLI is used like
`tsc <filename>` or just `tsc`. But whenever I try to do it like that, I get an error like

```
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

*But...* when I do

```
npx tsc
```

then it works!

#### So whats the problem?

The problem with doing `npx tsc` is because

1. npx is slow at executing commands
2. its annoying having to type `npx` and the front of every command.

And the thing is, this was originally not a problem with WSL.

##### Why dont you just use WSL?

I have always had problems with WSL (primarily permission issues due to security reasons) and so I uninstalled WSL and just used command prompt. I would have perferred using WSL but it was simply not an option.

Other Info:

- I am using Windows command prompt.
- I have installed the packages globally

So is there a way to just execute commands that way or is it Command prompts fault?

Comment: It seems you've installed the libraries locally instead of global. Global libraries are deployed to the main node folder with proper bat files for easy access (such as `tsc` and other such commands) and work as long as node is in the path environment variable. By installing them locally, you need to use `npx` everywhere.

Comment: @Alejandro right.... I forgot to mention I did install them globally. Sorry about that.

Comment: The real question is "why not use npx?" because that's the whole point of it: running project-local CLI tools without polluting your global installation. And you only need `npx` if you want to run things manually, inside npm scripts, you don't. On that note, why would you need to run `tsc` manually instead of having it be part of your project's build script(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### ***! this only works for Windows !***

Ok, so I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731872/expo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) and thankfully, the first answer there was the solution!

Just add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the path variable in system variables!

To access the system variables, press the Windows key, type `Environment  variables` and click on `Environment variables` at the bottom of the window. The path variable can be found under `User variables for (profile name)`.