# Expo cli wont install

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, hadoop-yarn

I can't install expo on a new pc i'm using Windows 10 and already installed node but when i use  `npm install --global expo-cli` cmd says that expo isnt a recognized command, i was running as and admin and try it using powershell but it didnt work, also using the yarn command habpens the same

edit1

i tried adding npm to path system variable but it didnt work, also i notice that it dont have anything inside, dont know if that is normal

[image]

after that i tried reinstaling everything, now i cant even install yarn

[image]

also the sames stills happens with expo

Answer (score 0):

Try to reopen your command-prompt or powershell [OR] try restarting your system [or] follow the link on StackOverflow:
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731872/expo-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: i tried all of it but dont work, also i tried unnistalling everything and now i cant even install yarn

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

STEP #1: `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`

STEP#2: `Nvm install node` (Note: install node using nvm, instead of npm on this step)

STEP #3: `Npm install -g expo-cli` (Note: install expo-cli using npm on this step)

STEP #4: `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` on terminal

STEP #5:

`expo init name_of_file`