# react-native' installation generates error as - 'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: react-native

First, 
npm install -g react-native-cli
command executed well.
but
react-native init SampleReactNativeProject
command generated error as - 
'react-native' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

I tried lot of solutions but not a single solution works for me.

I have installed node 8.9.4, npm 5.6.0, Android Studio 3.2.1.
Also I set variables -
C:\Users\JOHN\AppData\Roaming\npm,
D:\Android_Data\Android\sdk\platform-tools,
D:\Android_Data\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,
C:\Program Files\nodejs,

What to do now? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the command prompt? Perhaps this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/5508175

Comment: Yes, lot of times I have restarted command prompt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your `PATH` Environment Variable the location of your `npm`.
Usually it's located at:

`C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`

There you will find `react-native.cmd`

[image: reactnpm]

Answer (score 3):

see if your environment variable Exactly like below

### In your PATH Variable:

C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
C:\Program Files\nodejs

### In your system Variable

ANDROID_HOME C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

**It seems you have not set system variable
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191**
Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Please reinstall the nodejs. First, uninstall the nodejs on your system then install the stable version.

As TrakBit had solved the issue.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5620#issuecomment-176851774