# 'prisma' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, npm, prisma, prisma-graphql

Hi everyone I am getting this error **"'prisma' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."** while running prisma login command in cmd I have installed the prisma globally with **npm install -g prisma** any solution will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a problem with `prisma`, but with how you configured your PATH on Windows.

Windows doesn't know where is `prisma`, so you must tell him where to look.

See this answer to learn how to do that: [Nodejs cannot find installed module on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587665/nodejs-cannot-find-installed-module-on-windows)

Answer (score 14):

Install it globally with; `npm i -g prisma`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `prisma` installed in a local project:

```
npm i prisma @prisma/client
- or -
pnpm i prisma @prisma/client
- or -
yarn add prisma @prisma/client
```

Just call `prisma generate` like this ([docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#usage)):

```
npx prisma generate
- or -
pnpm dlx prisma generate
- or -
yarn prisma
```

It works for all other `node_modules` using CLI as well (also in Windows).

Answer (score 0):

> yarn add Prisma

please try this command